# Rendering model via nested templates in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building an app with multiple todo lists. The todo list used to correctly show todo model.

But I added function() to stack router to wrap todos router (so that it would correctly render todos template in stack template).

Then todos/index template (which is rendered through the outlet in todos) stopped displaying todo model.

This is my router structure:

```
Todos.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('stacks', {path: '/stacks'});
  this.resource('stack', {path: '/stacks/:stack_id'}, function () {

    this.resource('todos', { path: '/todos/:todos_id' }, function () {
        // additional child routes will go here later
        this.route('active');
        this.route('completed');
        this.route('new');

    });
    this.resource('todo', { path: 'todo/:todo_id' });

  });
});
```

Stack template which renders Todo template:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="stack">
        <h1>
          <label {{action "editStack" on="doubleClick"}}>{{stackTitle}}</label>

          {{input 
            value=stackTitle
            action="createStack"}}

        <div>{{model.stackTitle}}</div>

            </h1>

        {{render 'todos' todo}}

    </div>
  </script>
```

Then this todo template has an outlet for todo/index:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <section id="main">
      {{outlet 'todos/index'}}
      {{outlet modal}}
      {{input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all" checked=allAreDone}}
    </section>

  </div>

  </script>
```

And todo/index template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos/index">
    <ul id="todo-list">
    <li {{bind-attr class="todo.isCompleted:completed todo.isEditing:editing"}}>
      {{#each todo in model itemController="todo"}}

          {{#if todo.isEditing}}
              {{edit-todo class="edit" value=todo.title focus-out="acceptChanges"
                       insert-newline="acceptChanges"}}

          {{else}}                
            {{input type="checkbox" checked=todo.isCompleted class="toggle"}}
            {{outlet}}
            <button {{action 'openModal' 'modal' model}}>
            <label {{action "editTodo" on="doubleClick"}}>{{todo.title}}</label>
            </button>

          {{/if}}
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

  </script>
```

Routers:

```
Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('todo');
  },

});

Todos.TodosIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('todos');
  },
});
```

I've tried using {{partial}} helper in case that was a problem, but it didn't seem to change much.

Maybe I'm missing something in todos/index router that I need to call data through nested templates?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on here but I think the root of your problem is with the way that you're using `render` in your `templates/stack`.

Since your `routes/todos` route is nested inside your `routes/stack` route, you're going to want to use an `outlet` inside your `templates/stack` if you want any of the templates for the nested routes to be rendered.

When you use `render 'todos' todo`, you're saying to render `templates/todos` with the `todo` property from the `controllers/stack` as the model. This isn't going to use your `routes/todos` or `routes/todos-index` to set the `model`.

What you probably want is for your `templates/stack` to have an `{{outlet}}` that either the `routes/todos` or `routes/todo` is rendered into when you visit either of those routes.

Comment: Thank you! This clears up my confusion about outlets vs render. Although now I'm getting connectedOutlet error ha